# Proper suffix, suffix and empty string

Tags: formal-languages

I found this definition on Wikipedia.

Suffix. A suffix of a string is any substring of the string which includes its last letter, including itself. A proper suffix of a string is not equal to the string itself.

Is the empty string a suffix of itself?

if I have a language formed from f Σ = {a, b}, with a Kleene star.
How many elements from  Σ* can we form such that no two elements are a proper suffix of each other?

Edit:
is there a way to know how many Language of at most 2 letter strings formed from {a, b} where neither strings is a proper string of the other. Know the number without having to list all of them.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the definition given on Wikipedia. A word $s$ is a *suffix* of a word $w$ if there exists a word $u$ such that $w = us$. In particular, $s$ can be the empty word and the empty word is a suffix of itself.

For the second question, infinitely many. Just take the suffix code $ba^*$: $ba^i$ is a suffix of $ba^j$ if and only if $i = j$.

EDIT 1. I have now edited the [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) entry on Wikipedia.

EDIT 2. Up to taking the reversals of the words, your new question is asking for the number of sets $T \subset \{a,b\}^{\leqslant 2}$ such that no word of $T$ is a prefix of another word of $T$. Such a set is represented by a binary tree of depth $\leqslant 3$. Now this [detailed answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128257) by Brian M. Scott tells you that the number $b_n$ of binary trees of height $\leqslant n$ satisfies $b_{-1} = 1$, $b_0 = 2$ and $b_{n+1}=b_n^2+1$. Thus $b_1= 5$ and $b_2 = 26$. Thus the answer to your question is $26$. See also [OEIS A$003095$](http://oeis.org/A003095).

Comment: You should edit the wikipedia page - either correct it, or register the alternative definition.

Comment: The definition in Wikipedia was quite confusing. What if the language was formed from {a,b} but it was the language that only contains 2 strings. 
That should make it Finite. is there anyway to know how many elements it would have.

Comment: Good idea, I will edit wikipedia tomorrow (I need a bit of time to add the proper references)

Comment: @Takobell I don't understand your comment. What is "the language that only contains two strings"?

Comment: Language of at most 2 letter strings formed from {a, b} where neither strings is a proper string of the other

Comment: Well, if $L = \{aa,ab,ba,bb\}$, no word of $L$ is a proper factor of any other word of $L$.

Comment: Thanks that's an  obvious one but there should be more than 20 languages that meet those characteristics and, I can find more than 12

Comment: Is there a way to know how many that would be without listing all of them ?

Comment: This is another question. Comments are not an appropriate place to ask questions.

Comment: I am going to edit my question Thanks.